# The underlying query of a mapped attribute

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

If I have an sqlalchemy-mapped instance. Can I get an underlying dynamic query object corresponding to an attribute of said instance?

For example:

```
e = Employee()
e.projects

#how do I get a query object loaded with the underlying sql of e.projects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're describing the `lazy="dynamic"` property of `relationship()`.  something like

```
 class Employee(Base):
     __table_name__ = "employees"
     ...

     projects = relationship(..., lazy="dynamic")
```

which will cause `Employee().project` to return a `sqlalchemy.orm.Query` instance instead of a collection containing the related items.  However, that means there's no (simple) way to access the collection directly.  If you still need that (most likely you really do want it to be lazily loaded, set up two `relationship()`s instead.

```
 class Employee(Base):
     __table_name__ = "employees"
     ...

     projects_query = relationship(..., lazy="dynamic")
     projects = relationship(..., lazy="select")
```

edit: You said

> I need somehow to get the dynamic query object of an already lazy relationship mapped property.

Supposing we have an instance `i` of class `Foo` related to a class `Bar` by the property `bars`.  First, we need to get the property that handles the relationship.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import manager_of_class
p = manager_of_class(Foo).mapper.get_property('bars')
```

We'd like an expression that `and_`s together all of the columns on `i` that relate it to `bars`.  If you need to operate on `Foo` through an alias, substitute it in here.

```
e = sqlalchemy.and_(*[getattr(Foo, c.key) == getattr(i, c.key)
                      for c in p.local_side])
```

Now we can create a query that expresses this relationship.  Substitute aliases for `Foo` and `Bar` here as needed.

```
q = session.query(Foo) \
           .filter(e) \
           .join(Foo.bars) \
           .with_entities(Bar)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. However, I want that dynamically generated from existing properties after the instance and mapping is already done.

I need somehow to get the dynamic query object of an already lazy relationship mapped property.

Any clues?

Comment: Thank you TokenMacGuy!! What a clever solution!! Can't wait to try this in code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the question in general, but you definitely can enable SQL logging by setting [echo=True](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html?highlight=echo#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.echo), which will log the SQL statement as soon as you try to get value of the attribute.
Depending on your `relationship` configuration, it might have been eagerly pre-loaded.